# Setting a key field on a view

Tags: sql, view, ibm-midrange

I am creating an SQL view for a file that strips out the spaces in a particular field. My question is if there is a why to set a key on that new view so a person can still CHAIN the file. We are on V5R3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay found the answer at http://archive.midrange.com/midrange-l/200809/msg01062.html.

It is not possible at V5R3. Supposedly at V6R1 this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Could you accomplish the same thing using a logical file or with an `OPNQRYF` statement? Both of those allow you to set key fields and may be able to strip out the spaces in a file.

Answer (score 0):

Could you make a copy of the field with the spaces stripped out?  You can update the stripped out copy using a file trigger.  Then create an index/logical file over the stripped out copy of the field.